# How do I make a text to speach vbs script

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to make a VBS file that will say what I type my original code didn't work at all what must I do
`sapi.voice create box  sapi speak("Hello world")`

Comment: Refer to this https://www.reliance-scada.com/en/support/articles/technical/vbscript-tip-converting-alarm-event-text-to-speech

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim message, sapi
message=InputBox("What do you want me to say?","For all in need")

Set sapi=CreateObject("sapi.spvoice")
sapi.Speak message
```

Explanation:
This should work only for VBS. It should work for any device that supports VBS.
It displays a text box, this text box will display the message 'What do you want me to say'

And whatever you type it will say.